# Search view bar and other action bar icons are not working properly

Tags: java, android, sorting

I have implemented the search functionality in my android application along with the sorting of recycler view items in ascending and descending order.I have used action bar icons to perform these operations.My ascending and descending order icons works properly when I don't click search bar icon at all,but as soon as I click on my search bar icon to search something and then I try to sort my recycler view list by clicking on the sorting icons then it doesnt performs sorting.What is the issue?
Here is my code for my activity and adapter-->

**food_item_description.java**

```
public class food_item_description extends AppCompatActivity  implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{

    private food_description_adapter adapter;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    databasehandler db;
    private String Food_category;
    private List<food_items> food_itemses;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.food_description);

        db=databasehandler.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_view2);
        Food_category=getIntent().getStringExtra("category_food");

        setTitle(Food_category);
        food_itemses = new ArrayList<>();
        food_itemses.addAll(db.getAllfood_items(Food_category));
        adapter=new food_description_adapter(food_itemses);

        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new recycler_view_divider(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.food_items, menu);

        final MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search);
        final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(SEARCH_SERVICE);
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

        return true;

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
        // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.

        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.ascending:
                Collections.sort(food_itemses, new Comparator<food_items>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(food_items lhs, food_items rhs) {
                        return (int) (lhs.calorie-rhs.calorie);
                    }
                });

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                break;
            case R.id.descending:
                Collections.sort(food_itemses, new Comparator<food_items>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(food_items lhs, food_items rhs) {
                        return (int) (rhs.calorie-lhs.calorie);
                    }
                });

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                break;

            case R.id.menu_search:

                MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(item,
                        new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
                                // Do something when collapsed
                                adapter.setFilter(food_itemses);
                                return true; // Return true to collapse action view
                            }

                            @Override
                            public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
                                // Do something when expanded

                                return true; // Return true to expand action view
                            }
                        });
                break;


            default:
                break;

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        final List<food_items> filteredModelList = filter(food_itemses, newText);
        adapter.setFilter(filteredModelList);
        return true;
    }

    private List<food_items> filter(List<food_items> models, String query) {
        query = query.toLowerCase();

        final List<food_items> filteredModelList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (food_items model : models) {
            final String text = model.getfood_item().toLowerCase();
            if (text.contains(query)) {
                filteredModelList.add(model);
            }
        }
        return filteredModelList;
    }


}
```

**food_description_adapter.java**

```
public class food_description_adapter extends
        RecyclerView.Adapter<com.samarth.lightweight.database.food_description_adapter.ViewHolder>

{

private List<food_items> food_items;
private List<food_items> original_food_items;

public food_description_adapter(List<food_items> food_itemses) {
        food_items=food_itemses;
        original_food_items=food_itemses;
}


@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
        .inflate(R.layout.food_description_layout, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(itemView);
        }


public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    public TextView food_item;
    public TextView prot_value;
    public TextView fat_value;
    public TextView carb_value;
    public TextView cal_value;
    public ImageView bk,bk1;


    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        food_item = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.food_item);
        prot_value= (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.prot_value);
        fat_value= (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.fat_value);
        carb_value= (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.carb_value);
        cal_value= (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.cal_value);
        bk=(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.bk);
        bk1=(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.bk1);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)food_item.getLayoutParams();
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, R.id.bk1);
        food_item.setLayoutParams(params); //causes layout update

    }

}



    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final com.samarth.lightweight.database.food_description_adapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position)
    {
        com.samarth.lightweight.database.food_items food_item=food_items.get(position);
        viewHolder.food_item.setText(food_item.getfood_item());
        viewHolder.prot_value.setText(String.valueOf(food_item.getproteins())+ "g.");
        viewHolder.fat_value.setText(String.valueOf(food_item.getfat())+ "g.");
        viewHolder.carb_value.setText(String.valueOf(food_item.getcarb())+ "g.");
        viewHolder.cal_value.setText(String.valueOf(food_item.getcalorie()));
        viewHolder.bk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                viewHolder.bk.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                viewHolder.bk1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)viewHolder.food_item.getLayoutParams();
                params.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, R.id.bk1);
                viewHolder.food_item.setLayoutParams(params); //causes layout update

            }
        });
        viewHolder.bk1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                viewHolder.bk1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                viewHolder.bk.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)viewHolder.food_item.getLayoutParams();
                params.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, R.id.bk);
                viewHolder.food_item.setLayoutParams(params); //causes layout update

            }
        });

    }



    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        if(food_items!=null)
            return food_items.size();
        return 0;
    }
            public void setFilter(List<food_items> foods){
                food_items = new ArrayList<>();
                food_items.addAll(foods);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
}
```

**food_items.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/ascending"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_arrow_drop_up_white_24dp"
        android:title="Ascending"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/descending"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_arrow_drop_down_white_24dp"
        android:title="Descending"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_search"
        android:title="Search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"
        app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />


</menu>
```

[image: action bar display]

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by applying `MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener` in my `onCreateOptionsMenu` and therefore adding the following code  -

```
MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(searchItem,

                        new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
                                // Do something when collapsed
                                Log.i("search bar","collapsed");
                                adapter.setFilter(food_itemses);
                                return true; // Return true to collapse action view
                            }

                            @Override
                            public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
                                // Do something when expanded
                                Log.i("search bar","expanded");
                                return true; // Return true to expand action view
                            }
                        });
```

I also did some other changes as well .So here is my final improved code--

**food_item_description.java**

```
public class food_item_description extends AppCompatActivity implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{

    private food_description_adapter adapter;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    databasehandler db;
    private String Food_category;
    private List<food_items> food_itemses;
    private List<food_items> filtered_food_itemses;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.food_description);

        db = databasehandler.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view2);
        Food_category = getIntent().getStringExtra("category_food");

        setTitle(Food_category);
        food_itemses = new ArrayList<>();
        filtered_food_itemses=new ArrayList<>();

        food_itemses.addAll(db.getAllfood_items(Food_category));
        filtered_food_itemses.addAll(db.getAllfood_items(Food_category));
        adapter = new food_description_adapter(food_itemses);

        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new recycler_view_divider(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.food_items, menu);

        final MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search);
        final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
        MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(searchItem,

                        new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
                                // Do something when collapsed
                                Log.i("search bar","collapsed");
                                adapter.setFilter(food_itemses);
                                return true; // Return true to collapse action view
                            }

                            @Override
                            public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
                                // Do something when expanded
                                Log.i("search bar","expanded");
                                return true; // Return true to expand action view
                            }
                        });
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        return true;

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
        // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.

        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.ascending:
                Collections.sort(filtered_food_itemses, new Comparator<food_items>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(food_items lhs, food_items rhs) {
                        return (int) (lhs.calorie-rhs.calorie);
                    }
                });
                adapter.setFilter(filtered_food_itemses);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                break;
            case R.id.descending:
                Collections.sort(filtered_food_itemses, new Comparator<food_items>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(food_items lhs, food_items rhs) {
                        return (int) (rhs.calorie-lhs.calorie);
                    }
                });
                adapter.setFilter(filtered_food_itemses);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                break;

            default:
                break;

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

    private List<food_items> filter(List<food_items> models, String query) {
        query = query.toLowerCase();

        final List<food_items> filteredModelList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (food_items model : models) {
            final String text = model.getfood_item().toLowerCase();
            if (text.contains(query)) {
                filteredModelList.add(model);
            }
        }
        filtered_food_itemses=filteredModelList;
        return filteredModelList;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        final List<food_items> filteredModelList = filter(food_itemses, newText);
        adapter.setFilter(filteredModelList);
        return true;
    }
}
```